# Telerik MVC grid: drop down list in the filter dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I would like to use the built-in filter capabilities of the Telerik grid as described here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-filtering.html

The only problem is that we need to show a drop down list instead of a text box in the filter dialog for some columns.

So in this screenshot: 
[image]

The text box where it writes "Mario", should be a drop down list with items containing also Mario.

Comment: I need to show only one column. How to hide the filter icon other columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use foreign key columns as described it here : 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn